# ImageView src vs background

Tags: android, background, android-imageview, nine-patch

I an trying to use `Imageview` to overlay a bitmap over a layout.
From what I can see.

- if I use the bitmap (which is a 9-patch) as `android:src` it does not get streched to cover the layout
- if I use it as `android:background` it gets streched

My dilemma is that I want to use a bunch of 9-patchs in a `level-list` resource and select the right one using `setImageLevel()`.

- setImageLevel only works for `android:src` and not for `android:background`

How do I get the 9-patch also streched but also selectable from level-list?

Comment: Try using android:scaleType="fitXY" in the ImageView.

Comment: @SagarWaghmare I just tried your advise. It does scale the bitmap, but not as a 9-patch should stretch, it scales it raw.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using your `level-list` drawable as the background of the ImageView and then when you need to change the level: `LevelListDrawable background = (LevelListDrawable) findViewById(R.id.image).getBackground();background.setLevel(1);`

Comment: @Luksprog I think you are probably right. I moved on since, but I will go back to that and try it again. I think I maybe was using setLevel() only on the `Imageview` istself and not the background.

Comment: @Luksprog Confirmed! You are right. Please post the answer so I can mark the right answer for other programmers looking at this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `level-list` drawable. That drawable will be the background for the `ImageView`, to set the level to the desired value(and to make the proper drawable be selected) you'll use:

```
LevelListDrawable background = (LevelListDrawable) findViewById(R.id.image).getBackground();
background.setLevel(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Until a better answer shows up. Let me share how I do it now.
In code, instead of using:

```
myView.setImageLevel(level);
```

I just set the background there

```
switch(level) {
case 0:
    myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg0);
    break;    
case 1:
    myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg1);
    break;
    . . . 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the imageview of the xml, try adding the attribute:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```